# Is SQL injection possible with int data type?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm not using prepare or bind statement in my php code but I'm taking only int data for my search query so I just want to know where SQL injection is even possible with this query?

```
$enroll = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, intval($_POST['enroll']));

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Student_Data WHERE enroll=$enroll LIMIT 1");
```

I use `intval()` to take Int only input.

Thank you for the information.

Comment: you escaped it. but you really don't need to if you use parameterized queries.

Comment: @DanielA.White is still Sql injection is possbile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "mysqli\_real\_escape\_string" enough to avoid SQL injection or other SQL attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack)

Comment: Have a look at this question. It is the same as yours. :) https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/305299

Comment: @rickdenhaan no it does not answer my question I'm only taking integer input from user as you can see I converted user input into integer using **intval** so still sql is possible or not?

Comment: The question I linked to links to a details explanation of some *very obscure* edge-cases where SQL injection *may* be possible if you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. But your specific code example is not one of those edge-cases. Using `intval()`, it is not possible to inject custom SQL code into your query. *Maybe* there could be a DoS opportunity if you're running 64-bit PHP and 32-bit MySQL where PHP could send an integer value to MySQL that is larger than MySQL can handle in its 32 bits. But I haven't encountered 32-bit MySQL in quite a while.

Comment: The standard way is to use prepared statement which can help you avoid SQL injection. If your intension is to do that, why on earth are you trying not to use it?

Comment: I will never understand why people invest effort into finding workarounds instead of simply following the recommended and proven patterns. Use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" which works for _all_ cases. Not just for this one.

Comment: Why do things sloppily and check if they're safe in spefiic circumstances? Just do it right in the first place, it's the same simple code every time, why avoid it? If I found out about this approach during an interview, I'd straight up refuse to hire that candidate.

Comment: @arkascha, Keep in mind we see a self-selecting sample of such questions. It's possible that a majority of programmers know how to use bound parameters, but we still see a lot of examples of outdated coding methods on sites like Stack Overflow because overall the number of junior developers grows every year.

Comment: @BillKarwin I fail to see your point. While it certainly is true that people just starting to program do not have the experience I doubt that is the issue here. Look at the comments above: the OP reacts to the hints by wiping them aside ...

Answer (score 0):

In general, **No** It is not possible. But if your intension is to protect from SQL injection, why you should not use the better way which is proven? Overall, nothing can be guaranteed tomorrow. So better choice is to use the best practice what is available today.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, escaping is **always** context-dependent. The context `mysqli_real_escape_string` is designed for is *inside a single-quoted string in an SQL query*. If you are using the string in any other context, *do not use that function*. For instance, this is *not* secure:

```php
$input = "a + ' + b";
$sql = "Select * From whatever Where something=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $input);
```

The result is this:

```sql
Select * From whatever Where something=a + '' + b
```

So you've gone from a syntax error to a valid, and user-controlled, query.

For that reason, **applying both `intval` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` never makes sense**: if you're using the value in an integer context, it's simply the wrong function, and a symptom of the dangerous mentality that "more escaping is better".

---

Secondly, understand what the functions you're using actually do: `intval` converts any PHP value, if it can, to an integer; then the `.` operator will always convert its operands to strings. So `$anything . intval($input)` is always converting `$input` first to an integer, and then to a string.

So, certainly we can predict exactly what characters are possible to end up in the query - digits 0 to 9, and the `-` sign. It's just about possible that some obscure bug in the database or driver could misinterpret those in such a way as to have unintended consequences, but it's pretty unlikely.

---

Thirdly, if you have the choice, **just use parameters and the whole thing becomes irrelevant**.

Remember that, since you no longer have the context it works with, you should *not* also use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.